# Modification of Bokeh plot to be able to select data points

Tags: javascript, python, plot, bokeh

I'm trying to get a list of the points that have been clicked on a graph, but i'm getting an empty list each time. The purpose of this is to allow my colleagues to click on interested data points on a graph, and for the clicked points to be recorded for other work.

I am modifying code from the Chemplot python module:
Line tha creates plot with colourmap:

```
circle_plot = p.circle(x=x, y=y, size=2.5, alpha=0.8, line_color=index_cmap, fill_color=index_cmap,
                     source=df_data)
                color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, location=(0,0))
                p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
```

Part that I have added to get the list of datapoints:

```
                taptool = TapTool(renderers=[circle_plot])
                p.add_tools(taptool)    

                
                code = """
                var inds = source.selected.indices;
                var d1 = source.data;
                var indices = [];
                
                for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
                    indices.push(d1['index'][inds[i]]);
                }
                
                console.log(indices);
                """
            
                # Convert the DataFrame to a ColumnDataSource
                source = ColumnDataSource(df_data)
                
                # Then pass the ColumnDataSource into the CustomJS callback
                callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code=code)

                
                # Associate the callback with taptool
                taptool.callback = callback
```

Instead of returning the datapoints indices it returns a blank array.